# Nx project with multiple files output

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nrwl-nx

I have a simple [Nx project](https://nx.dev/) with 2 **TypeScript** files and I want to generate the output being their associated 2 JavaScript files.

My **project.json** file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/my-project/src",
  "tags": ["type:script"],
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-project",
        "index": "",
        "main": "apps/my-project/src/one.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/my-project/tsconfig.app.json",
        "generateIndexHtml": false,
        "webpackConfig": "apps/my-project/webpack.config.js"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "none",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "vendorChunk": false
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
       ...
    },
    "lint": {
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change this configuration if I have **one.ts** and **two.ts** files and I want to output with **one.js** and **two.js** files?